# Unable to parse data from an xml file in the Parse Cloud using xmlreader in express app

Tags: javascript, express, xml-parsing, parse-platform

My objective is to get elements of an xml file which i already saved on Parse Cloud for my express app. I started coding after referring [this](https://parse.com/questions/htmlxml-parser-with-xpath-on-cloud-code) for xmlreader 
and the guide on Parse httpRequest to retrieve parse file. I tested reading xml elements using xmlreader like this:

```
exports.xmlmodule = function(req, res) {
if (Parse.User.current()){
Parse.User.current().fetch().then(function(user){
var xmlreader = require('cloud/xmlreader');

var someXml =     '<dataset>'
        +         '<brands>'
        +            '<TheId>1</TheId>'
        +            '<ParentId></ParentId>'
        +            '<CategoryorProductName>Casuals</CategoryorProductName>'
        +         '</brands>'
        +         '<brands>'
        +            '<TheId>34</TheId>'
        +            '<ParentId>1</ParentId>'
        +            '<CategoryorProductName>Jeans</CategoryorProductName>'
        +         '</brands>'
        +    '</dataset>'


xmlreader.read(someXml, function (err, res){
if(err) return console.log(err);

// using the .count() and the .at() function, you can loop through nodes with the same         name:
for(var i = 0; i < res.dataset.brands.count(); i++){
    console.log( res.dataset.brands.TheId.at(i).text() );
    console.log( res.dataset.brands.ParentId.at(i).text() );
    console.log( res.dataset.brands.CategoryorProductName.at(i).text() );
}

console.log("");


});


});}
else{ res.render('login',{welcome: 'Please login to continue'});}
 };
```

and it worked. (Please ignore the 'user' fetch which is not relevant here).

Then i tried to get xml file from parse cloud using httprequest and it also worked.

Now when i combine both these to get to my objective, i get an error:

```
Failed with: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'charAt'
at Object.write (sax.js:918:31)
at Object.exports.read (xmlreader.js:157:12)
at main.js:21:11
at e (Parse.js:2:5101)
at Parse.js:2:4651
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:665)
at c.extend.resolve (Parse.js:2:4602)
at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:573:17)
```

I used cloud function and here is my main.js

```
require ('cloud/app.js');
var xmlreader = require('cloud/xmlreader');
Parse.initialize("xxxxx", "xxxxx");

Parse.Cloud.define('myxmlfunction',function(req,res){
Parse.User.current().fetch().then(function(user){
var theid= user.get('StoreId');
var Stores= Parse.Object.extend('Stores');
var query= new Parse.Query(Stores);
query.equalTo('objectId', theid);
query.first().then(function(results){
var xmlfile= results.get('xmlfile');
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
url: xmlfile.url()
}).then(function(thefile){

var file = new Parse.File('thexml.xml', {
 base64: thefile.buffer.toString("base64")
});

xmlreader.read(file, function (err, res){
if(err) return console.log(err);

// using the .count() and the .at() function, you can loop through nodes with the same name:
 for(var i = 0; i < res.myrecord.brands.count(); i++){
     console.log( res.myrecord.brands.TheId.at(i).text() );
      console.log( res.myrecord.brands.ParentId.at(i).text() );
     console.log( res.myrecord.brands.CategoryorProductName.at(i).text() );
 }

 console.log("");

 });

 file.save().then(function() {
 res.success();
 }, function(error) {
 res.error(error);
 });
  });
  });
  });
  });
```

Note: the error shown in log main.js 21:11 points to "xmlreader.read". So obviously the xml file being retrieved from cloud is unable to be browsed through by xmlreader.

My xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <myrecord>
    <brands>
       <TheId>a</TheId>
       <PId > g</PId>          
       <CategoryNameorProductName >Martin</CategoryNameorProductName>
    </brands>
    <brands>
       <TheId>b</TheId>
       <PId > c</PId>           
       <CategoryNameorProductName >Levis</CategoryNameorProductName>
    </brands> 
</myrecord>
```

Note error 'charAt'.
I started coding a month before and looked at w3 xml tuts today noon. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. First of all there was a typo in XMl file. Replace "PId" with "ParentId". But the error relevant to the question was that..like @timothy suggested, the result of the httpRequest method lies in 'thefile' and the file is in 'thefile.buffer'. For xmlreader input use: thefile.buffer.toString(). There was also error in the looping function in main.js as i misplaced the .at(). I'm attaching the final code to **Retrieve xml file from Parse Cloud and get its node elements using xmlreader**

```
require ('cloud/app.js');
var xmlreader = require('cloud/xmlreader');
Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxx");

Parse.Cloud.define('myxmlfunction',function(req,res){
Parse.User.current().fetch().then(function(user){
var theid= user.get('StoreId');
var Stores= Parse.Object.extend('Stores');
var query= new Parse.Query(Stores);
query.equalTo('objectId', theid);
query.first().then(function(results){
var xmlfile= results.get('xmlfile');
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
url: xmlfile.url()
}).then(function(thefile){

xmlreader.read(thefile.buffer.toString(), function (err, res){
if(err) return console.log(err);

// using the .count() and the .at() function, you can loop through nodes with the same name:
 for(var i = 0; i < res.myrecord.brands.count(); i++){
    console.log( res.myrecord.brands.at(i).TheId.text() );
    console.log( res.myrecord.brands.at(i).ParentId.text() );
    console.log( res.myrecord.brands.at(i).CategoryNameorProductName.text() );
}

console.log("");

});


}).then(function() {
res.success();
}, function(error) {
res.error(error);
 });
});
});
});
```

and xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myrecord>
    <brands>
       <TheId>a</TheId>
       <ParentId > g</ParentId>          
       <CategoryNameorProductName >Martin</CategoryNameorProductName>
    </brands>
    <brands>
       <TheId>b</TheId>
       <ParentId > c</ParentId>           
       <CategoryNameorProductName >Levis</CategoryNameorProductName>
    </brands> 
</myrecord>
```

And the log result:

```
Input: {}
Result: undefined
I2014-07-29T05:56:42.879Z] Levis
I2014-07-29T05:56:42.880Z]  c
I2014-07-29T05:56:42.881Z] a
I2014-07-29T05:56:42.881Z] b
I2014-07-29T05:56:42.881Z] Martin
I2014-07-29T05:56:42.884Z] 
I2014-07-29T05:56:42.885Z]  g
```

I'll surely take care of typos in future.

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding your Parse.File instance (`file`) into the XmlReader, instead of the actual string that it wants.

You have the actual file in your `thefile` variable, so use that instead.

The Parse.File class is for when you want to save a file onto the cloud and store a pointer to it in a class.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. But it didn't work when i used 'thefile' variable, returning same error. I have two doubts now.1. Is 'thefile' a file? coz in Parse docs, it was mentioned that the file would be in (in this case) thefile.buffer. 2. how can i get the 'actual strings' from it to input the xmlreader? If you think i need to read some docs, please provide links. Thanks

Comment: Also please verify my loop function...I'm bit doubtful on that!